# Calling methods which take interfaces as arguments

Tags: c#

In the following code, why is the `F(Test x)` function required. Shouldn't the `F(TestInterface x)` function be called whenever a `TestInterface` is passed to `F`? Hence, shouldn't having `F(TestInterface x)` satisfy both the interfaces `SillyInterface<Test>` and `SillyInterface<TestInterface>`?

Is there a way to avoid the two definitions of `F` here?

```
public class Test : TestInterface, SillyInterface<Test>
{
  public static void Main() {}

  public void F(TestInterface x) {}

  // Why is the definition below required?
  public void F(Test x) { F((TestInterface) x); }
}

public interface TestInterface : SillyInterface<TestInterface> {}

public interface SillyInterface<T> 
{
  void F(T x);
}
```

Comment: You have the `SillyInterface<Test>` interface defined on the class so stand to reason that its contract should be honored as well

Comment: Doesn't `F(TestInterface)` honour the `SillyInterface<Test>` contract, as `TestInterface` is an interface of `Test`? If not, why not?

Comment: No. You are confusing how interfaces work.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Clinton - `SillyInterface<TestInterface>` can not provide the implementation for `SillyInterface<Test>` - even though it is true that `Test` "is-a" `TestInterface` it is not true that `SillyInterface<TestInterface>` "is-a" `SillyInterface<Test>`. It should be fairly obvious if you go ahead and create a new class called `Test2` that implements `TestInterface` then calling `F(Test2)` would succeed if `SillyInterface<TestInterface>` were allowed, but it's not because only `SillyInterface<Test>` is allowed.

Comment: While I appreciate the professional curiosity, I have to say that If any of my dev team would ever write code like that I would do all I can to get them fired. Even with meaningful names this kind of circular referencing is a maintenance nightmare and should be avoided at almost all costs.

Comment: You might want to read about [Covariance and Contravariance.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)